# Highlight the input field for error with jquery like twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, validation, input, highlight

I have the below sample html code, where i am trying to highlight the input field like input field validation in twitter bootstrap

```
<html>
<head>
$('#submit_form').submit(function(){
     var vals = $('.validate').val()
     if (!vals) 
        {
          console.log('Error exists');
          $('.validate').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
          $('.validate').val('enter a value');
        }   
});
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" id="submit_form">
      <div>
        <input class="validate" type="text" name="Name"/>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So by the above code the value `"enter a value"` is updating in the field, but the field is not highlighting

Also when i checked whether the style attribute has added to input.. and yes it was added successfully but why the field is not highlighting

Comment: border css shorthand is `<width> <style> <color>`, not `<color> <width> <style>`; also, better using classes over inline styles

Comment: it works fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRvF6/)

Comment: yeah actually identified the problem, i had the design templates, so in that input fields has defined some custom classes, so tried by removing that css file and with plain html input fields, and then it worked, need to check the default classes written on how to avoid this hope so .... :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
$('.validate').css({ "border": '#FF0000 1px solid'});
```

by replacing

```
$('.validate').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
```